# Batch file: store lines of command's output without writing to a file?

Tags: batch-file, count, lines

Windows XP

My batch file runs a command that has several lines of output.  How can I count (and store in a variable) the lines of output without ever writing to the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample script that will count the lines in the output of the `dir` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set lc=0

for /f "usebackq delims=_" %%i in (`dir`) do (
  echo %%i
  set /a lc=!lc! + 1
)

echo %lc%

endlocal
```

You can substitute `dir` with your command and you can use quotes and specify parameters. You will have to escape some other characters though - `^`, `|` `<` `>` and `&`.

If you need to not only count the lines, but also parse each line, you might have to change the token delimiter from `_` (as I used in the example) to something else that will not result in the line split in multiple tokens.

Comment: You can specify an empty delimiter list to prevent tokenizing with just `delims=` without anything following the `=`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that option. How I miss my Windows shell Programming reference book sometimes... :-)

Comment: There is a Windows shell programming reference book? :O Give it to me! :D ... You also don't need delayed expansion. `set /a lc+=1` will do.

Answer (score 3):

```
dir | find /v /c "zzzxxx"
```

gives a line count

Answer (score 0):

and while you are at it, you can also download [GNU packages(coreutils)](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) for windows and use the wc tool: eg

```
dir | wc -l
```